# Django - When button is clicked I want to change the dictionary content

Tags: python, html, django, button, dictionary

On my html page I have a button, and a number being displayed.  I want the number to increase by 1 every time the button is pressed.  This is the code that I have so far, but for some it doesn't work.

mypage.html

```html
<form method='get' action='#'>
    <input type="submit" value="add" name="add"/>
</form>
<h1>{{ p }}</h1>
```

views.py

```python
p = 1
def mypage(request):
    global p
    my_dictionary = {
        "p" : p,
    }
    if request.GET.get('add'):
        p = p+1
        my_dictionary = {
            "p" : p,
        }
    return render(request, "mypage.html", my_dictionary)
```

Comment: I am afraid variables, even global variables, are not kept in memory from one view call to the next. Normally a DB is used to make such data persist (or a file, or ....)

Comment: Sounds more like a task for a front-end library like AngularJS.  http://www.codecademy.com/ has an AngularJS course that completes that exact task. After AngularJS has let the user increment the value to whatever you are aiming for, then you can use Django to save the results into a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every request a new instance of the python script is run which would result in your global variable not being retained.  You should store the count in a database and recall the value on every request.  There are options other than a database but the basic idea of needing some sort of persistent storage still exists.

Alternatively, you can have the requester keep track of the count and provide the current count in the request.  You would then add one to the value provided in the request.  This would require some additional code on the front end to maintain the count, and even then, if the user closes the browser the count will be reset.

As dm03514 pointed out, you can can also use sessions like so:

```
if 'p' in request.session:    
   request.session['p'] = request.session['p'] + 1
else:
   request.session['p'] = 1
```

Comment: Every time the add button is clicked it does +1, so it works, but the count does not reset to 1 when you refresh the page.  How would I be able to fix that?

Comment: A simple solution would be to create a new view which will clear the session variable 'p'.  On page load you would simply call the view.

Answer (score 0):

The p value needs to be kept track of across requests.

2 possibilities are

- resend the data every request
- store the data in a session and just make increment /decrement requests

Should the variable be shared between all users? Or just the current user?

Comment: I want the variable to only be shared by the current user, and can you please explain further I am confused as to what to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if there is a single instance of django running (although it is not the recommended approach like other's have suggested).
It didn't appear to work is because you used `action='#'`, and the browser refused to resubmit the form when your URL already ends with `#`. Instead you can use the following template:

```
<form method='get' action='.'>
    <input type="submit" value="add" name="add"/>
</form>
<h1>{{ p }}</h1>
```